# Remove "empty" selection from dropdown list box

Tags: forms, orbeon

When creating a form in Orbeon Form Builder, you can define a list of values for a dropdown list box.

When running the form in form runner, is it possible to remove the "[Select...]" value from this dropdown list box?

I would like to restrict the possible values only to the given ones and restricting the user from selecting an "[Select...]" value when filling in the form. I hope you understand what I mean :)

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5N89.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without changes to Orbeon Forms to remove the empty option.

The best way to achieve what you want is to make the field *required*. When that's the case, the user will have to select a value or validation won't pass.

(The rationale for adding/keeping an empty option at the top is to force the user to make a selection. Otherwise it is possible that users might not even look at the option selected by default, and involuntarily select an incorrect option.)